# Template deduction with smart pointers

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

My code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class myClass
{
    int a;
};

template <typename T, template<typename ValueType> class SmartPtr> // (1)
void myFunction(const void *pointer, SmartPtr<T>& pointer2)
{
    cout<<"with template"<<endl;
}

void myFunction(const void *pointer, unique_ptr<myClass>& pointer2)
{
    cout<<"without template "<< *(static_cast<const int*>(pointer))<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    int* a = new int(5);
    unique_ptr<myClass> myUniquePtr(new myClass);
    shared_ptr<myClass> mySharedPtr(new myClass);

    myFunction(static_cast<const void*>(a), myUniquePtr); // (2)
    myFunction<int, unique_ptr<myClass> >(static_cast<const void*>(a), myUniquePtr); // (3)
    myFunction<int, shared_ptr<myClass> >(static_cast<const void*>(a), mySharedPtr); // (4)

    delete a;

    return 0;
}
```

Calling 'myFunction' in (2) is OK - it calls 'myFunction' without template. But in (3) and (4) compiler can't deduce template arguments. It generates errors:

`no matching function for call to ‘myFunction(const void*, std::unique_ptr<myClass>&)'` 
and 
`no matching function for call to ‘myFunction(const void*, std::shared_ptr<myClass>&)'`
respectively.

The question is how to change the second argument of template in (1) so I can instantiate template with arbitrary smart pointer? I want to omit `ValueType` and use `T`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling it like `myFunction<myClass, unique_ptr<myClass>>`?  Right now you are supplying `int` as the first template argument, which makes no sense.

Comment: A template template parameter isn't a great idea. `unique_ptr`, for instance, has two template parameters, not one. Take a normal type parameter, then use `std::pointer_traits` to extract the value type. Also, there's no reason to cast a pointer to `void *`.

Comment: Reguardless of how you do it, by supplying the template arguments you are stating that you cannot use the non-templated overload of the function call. Try specialization rather than overloading?

Comment: Yes, in code above it doesn't make sense but in my project code `T` will always be a type that could be put in `SmartPtr<T>`. The thing is that I want to run this function when any smart pointer is passed as second argument, not normal pointer.

Answer (score 9):

There is no need to have two template arguments, and this will cause problems for smart pointers that are using a custom allocator.  Just have one template argument: the type of smart pointer.

```
template <typename T>
void myFunction(const void *pointer, T & pointer2)
{
}
```

So `T` is the smart pointer type.  If you need access to the type of the managed object (`myClass` in this case) you can use `typename std::pointer_traits<T>::element_type`.

```
template <typename T>
void myFunction(const void *pointer, T & pointer2)
{
    typedef typename std::pointer_traits<T>::element_type obj_type;

    obj_type & o = *pointer2;
}
```

(Of course if you are using C++11 you could also just use `decltype(*pointer2)` or even `auto`.)

With this approach you can even use raw pointers as `T`, assuming that none of your logic depends on them being smart pointers.

---

As a side note, your invocation likely fails because you are supplying `int` as the `T` template argument, which doesn't make any sense; you should be using `myClass` there.

Comment: I'd suggest [`std::pointer_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/pointer_traits).

Answer (score 2):

We have `template <class T, class D = default_delete<T>> class unique_ptr;`

So your function template should look like:

```
template <template<typename, typename> class SmartPtr, typename T, typename D>
void myFunction(const void *pointer, SmartPtr<T, D>& pointer2)
{
    std::cout << "with template" << std::endl;
}
```

but it may be simpler to use something like in cdhowie's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is complaining is because you are giving it a type as the second template argument, but it expects a template (because you used template-template syntax.) The following should at least get it past the template expansion step of compilation (warning, not compiled, but you should get the idea)

```
myFunction<int, unique_ptr>(static_cast<const void*>(a), myUniquePtr); // (3)
myFunction<int, shared_ptr>(static_cast<const void*>(a), mySharedPtr); // (4)
```

But, as others have said, you probably don't need this. Just let template argument deduction happen instead of spelling it out.

Comment: Plus, the `int` type is wrong -- that would imply a `unique_ptr<int>` for example, which is not what we have here.

Comment: That's correct, and hence why I've eluded to yours and others answers. However the fundamental reason why it's not compiling is because the author is not giving the correct kind of template parameter. Whether or not the resulting code makes sense is a different topic ;)